# C# MVC after submit, data is changed

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

This is a very strange issue. I have a webpage that displays each view model returned from a search in a form for editing.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.qaJobsVM) {
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EditJobAdmin", "QualityAssurance",
            FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-style-11", @style = "display: inline-block;" })) {
```

If a user searches for a job number they get each one back correctly.

```
    public ActionResult EditJobAdmin(int JobNumber) {
        QAService qaService = new QAService(_qaContext);
        UpdateViewModelQA updateViewModelQA = new UpdateViewModelQA();
        updateViewModelQA.qaJobsVM = qaService.GetJobsByNumber(JobNumber);
        if (updateViewModelQA.qaJobsVM == null) {              
            ModelState.AddModelError("ExceptionError", "Could not find job.");
            return View("SearchJobAdmin", null);
        } else {
            return View(updateViewModelQA);
        }
    }
```

If they update any of the forms, the data is updated correctly and the search is ran again (to update the page). Oddly though, the same search is called, the same results are returned (except the changes they submitted), but all of the forms display the model from the user updated.

```
   [HttpPost] public ActionResult EditJobAdmin(JobViewModel item) {
        var qaService = new QAService(_qaContext);
        UpdateViewModelQA updateViewModelQA = new UpdateViewModelQA();

        if (!qaService.ValidErrorNumber(item.ErrorNumber)) {
            updateViewModelQA.qaJobsVM = qaService.GetJobsByNumber(item.JobNumber);
            ModelState.AddModelError("ExceptionError", "Invalid Error Number");
            return View(updateViewModelQA);
        }
        var JobUpdated = qaService.AdminUpdateJob(item, _errorLogService, HttpContext.User.ToString());
        updateViewModelQA.qaJobsVM = qaService.GetJobsByNumber(item.JobNumber);
        ModelState.AddModelError("ExceptionError", "Success!");
        return View(updateViewModelQA);
    }
```

[Search for job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYiFW.png)

[Debug info from search job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDg24.png)

[Debug info from submitting the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrsfv.png)

[After the page loads with the debug info from image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdMSy.png)

It's calling the same function to get the view models and the data is coming back correctly. If i debug the razor page it shows the correct info but then when the page finishes loading it shows the record that was updated as every view (for however many records it found)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example in text:
I look up job 12345. Job 12345 has 3 entries returned.

```
job: 12345
comment: comment number 1
job: 12345
comment: comment number 2
job: 12345
comment: comment number 3
```

I update the **first** returned item with the comment: "comment number 99"
The when the page finishes loading i get:

```
job: 12345
comment: comment number 99
job: 12345
comment: comment number 99
job: 12345
comment: comment number 99
```

If i search for job 12345 i get:

```
job: 12345
comment: comment number 99
job: 12345
comment: comment number 2
job: 12345
comment: comment number 3
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The returned data is shown in the 3rd image but the 4th image is what is displayed to the user. I don't understand why when i have it build the page i see all of the correct data but when the page finishes loading i get copies of whichever one was updated last.

Comment: I'm curious about this line of your code: `updateViewModelQA.qaJobsVM = qaService.GetJobsByNumber(item.JobNumber);`. It's changing your ViewModel. You should consider it first.

Comment: If i debug on that line, i get the third image back. which shows it just before it's sent to the page and the data is correct (aka NOT duplicated)

Comment: In this case it's better to put a breakpoint on entry point and go through it line by line.

Comment: Change your foreach loop to for loop and see what will happen.